# The difference between "wach" and "erwacht"?

Tags: adjective

I don't know what is the difference between "wach" and "erwacht", specially in this sentence: "Du bist noch nicht ganz erwacht." or "Du bist noch nicht ganz wach." Could anyone please describe me the difference?

Comment: VTC. Please tell us why a dictionary didn't help you: [dict.cc | erwacht](http://dict.cc?s=erwacht) [dict.cc | wach](http://dict.cc?s=wach)

Comment: I am neither native English nor German, I did not understand the difference from the dictionary.

Comment: So you cannot understand the difference between awakend/woken up vs. awake/woke? (this would be the fitting english version here). Hm, what did you assume the difference/similarity is? (while saying that: yes, the difference is quite small)

Comment: I can't understand the difference/similarity! "Du bist noch nicht ganz erwacht." and "Du bist noch nicht ganz wach." have the same meaning?

Answer (score 4):

There is not much of a difference in the meaning. The verb in infinite itself e.g. on [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/erwachen): switching from the state of sleeping to being awake.

> Du bist noch nicht ganz erwacht. *vs.*  Du bist noch nicht ganz wach.

The main difference:

- style of writing

common usage:

- "erwachen" is a process over a time period
- "wach sein" is a state at a point in time

  - which derives the meaning mainly from "sein"

=> "erwacht sein" is also a point in time and might refer to the end of an awakening process while "wach sein" does not talk about the process.

In your example there is no real difference - I guess either one of it was used beforehand so it was used again.

Example:

- there is a religious group with their paper called "Erwachet!"

  - they claim that you need to go through a process and at the end you understand their version of truth.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

*Erwacht* concentrates on the transition between sleeping and awake, so the sleeping unawareness is still important. It is also used figuratively to describe the establihment of feelings, moods etc.

*Wach* is simply the state. This is too used figuratively, but then means something like *alert*, *keen*, *sharp*